# Does $\frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}$ have a Laplace Transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I tried considering the integral:

$$\mathcal{L}[{f(t)}](s) =  \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}\,dt,$$

but the function $f(t) = \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t^2}$ has a vertical asymptote at $t_0 = 0$, therefore this integral isn't defined... does this make sense?

Comment: The integral doesn't converge because of the way $t^{-2}$ behaves at the origin. Now if there was a shift, like $\sin(t-1)/(t-1)^2,$ or $\sin(t)u(t-1)/t^2,$ those might have an LT since the asymptote is no longer in the interval of integration, and the function is of exponential order. Don't know if you could get a closed-form expression for it, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our professor mentioned that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ does have a laplace transform once in class though, why would it behave differently?

Comment: The functions $1/t^2$ and $1/\sqrt{t}$ have opposite behaviors at the origin versus at infinity. $\int_0^1 t^{-2}\,dt$ d.n.e., while $\int_1^\infty t^{-2}\,dt$ does exist. $\int_0^1 t^{-1/2}\,dt$ exists, while $\int_1^\infty t^{-1/2}\,dt$ d.n.e. So the $t^{-1/2}$ is of exponential order and its integral near the origin is well-behaved, so it has a chance of having an LT (which is $\sqrt{\pi}/\sqrt{s}$), whereas $1/t^2$ cannot have an LT because the necessary integral diverges.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try to use this approach to prove why the integral doesn't exist for the original function.